# convert cygwin bash into tcsh

Tags: cygwin

how can I be able to convert my cygwin bash into a c Shell.
I have tried by changing the `.bat` file in installation directory like:
`@echo off

@echo                           ----Welcome NAME----

@echo                              'have a nice day'

cygdrive\

chdir \

set HOME=\cygwin\home\

tcsh -i`
please help.
Is it right process?
though it is working for me a bit...
any ideas...?

Comment: `@echo ...` is clearly a DOS batch-file-ism. I don't see anything here that is bash. Why do you want to use `tcsh`. If you're going to be writing a lot of scripts, `bash` is the clearly preferred choice. If you choose to answer these questions, please edit your main question, and don't reply here. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter - the user is trying to have the cygwin startup bat file launch a tcsh shell, rather than the bash shell it defaults to.  Shell preference is basically a religious war issue, so not worth debating.

Comment: @shelter: sure, he wrote that he's changing `.bat` (Windows batch) file, which executes Cygwin's shell. You should read better. He clearly don't want to use it for scripting but as an interactive shell.

Answer (score 4):

To change your Cygwin shell, you can alter the `/etc/passwd` file. Each line is a delimited list of user accounts, where the last entry is the shell for that user. Simply change the line that reads, for example:

```
abhisek:[some other stuff]:/usr/bin/bash
```

to:

```
abhisek:[some other stuff]:/usr/bin/tcsh
```

Comment: See also: Wikipedia's [passwd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passwd_%28file%29) article and http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

Comment: This is right, but it doesn't help at all when there is `bash` hardcoded in `cygwin.bat` which he uses for executing the shell. He need to execute something instead, what checks his default shell (in `passwd`) and executes it. But what's that?

Comment: I'm not sure this is an issue any more as Cygwin ships with MinTTY, nowadays, which does everything automagically. (Similarly, I use PuTTY.) I can't think why anyone would want to use *sh within the Windows command prompt.

Comment: MinTTY and PuTTY are too simple for heavy usage. If you would like to use ConEmu, what's the best console emulator for Windows, you have the same problem as with plain `cmd.exe`. I wonder, if the logic, which checks user's default shell is hardcoded in MinTTY, or it just executes something, what does the magic (check user's default shell and execute it).

Answer (score 2):

The current version of Cygwin doesn't have an  **/etc/passwd**  file, and the system I'm working on has Windows account information in a domain database out of my control. Consequently,  **chsh**  is no longer supported.

I also found that  **bash**  is not hard-coded into the  **startxwin**  script, nor is it hard-coded in any  **.bat** file.  Turns out you don't need to fiddle with  **.bat**  files at all.

Searching for how to change my shell, I found some advice about  **mkpasswd**

I added it to the mix.

The man-page said:

> ```
> SYNOPSIS
>    mkpasswd [OPTIONS]...
>
> OPTIONS
>    Don't use this command to generate a local /etc/passwd file, unless you
>    really need one.  See the Cygwin User's Guide for more information.
>
>    -c,--current
>           Print current user.
>
>   DESCRIPTION
>         The   mkpasswd  program can be used to create a        /etc/passwd
>    file.  Cygwin doesn't need  this  file,        because  it  reads  user
>    information  from  the Windows account databases,       but you can add
>    an  /etc/passwd file, for instance       if your machine is often  dis‐
>    connected from its domain controller.
>
>         Note  that this information is static, in contrast to the informa‐
>    tion       automatically gathered by Cygwin from  the  Windows  account
>    databases.  If        you  change  the user information on your system,
>    you'll need to regenerate       the passwd file for it to have the  new
>    information.
>
>
>         For  very  simple needs, an entry for the current user can be cre‐
>    ated       by using the option  -c.
> ```

(I don't know why the spacing is so "off"...)

I then used the following command:

**mkpasswd -c | sed -e 'sX/bashX/tcshX' | tee -a /etc/passwd**

and voila! the next time I opened a Cygwin Terminal, it went straight to tcsh

And that's the way (Uh-huh, uh-huh!) I like it.